# How to fit many datasets at once with a cross-validated pipeline?

Tags: cross-validation, optimization, hyperparameter

Basically, I need to find a pipeline that will not only be the best on one dataset, but to be the best in average across an ensemble of dataset.

How would you solve this problem using a cross-validated pipeline (e.g.: Scikit-learn)? The thing is that it's made for fitting only one dataset, but I have a list of datasets.

Would you simply find the best classifier for each dataset, and then train another pipeline for fitting the problem of "x = dataset" and "y = estimated best hyperparameters for this dataset"?

I'd still prefer something simpler but that would perform good enough. Would you have another solution?

## **Note: this question is more about Machine Learning strategies than coding. The coding part here is optional. It's bad to see this question on hold. The reason for the question to be on hold is wrong. I don't see why this question should not be on the cross-validated stack exchange. Bad moderation on this question is wrong and would make this site poorer than it is already. If you believe this question doesn't belong here, please move it instead of putting it on hold. Thanks.** Please read the new Code of Conduct as posted on Hacker News 5 hours ago: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17715193

Other note: I've already tried to figure this out with Scikit-learn but I'm seeking a potentially simpler solution than what I thought of.

Comment: As it is, I don't think the question is answerable. What may be sensibly done will depend a lot on e.g. how similar the data sets in the list are. Also global vs. local modeling decisions (one model for the whole list vs. one model for each data set or one set of hyperparameters for all data sets vs. individual hyperparameter optimization per data set) IMHO can only be answered taking into account detailed background knowledge about both application and data generating process.

Comment: I don't know the history of this post, but the large bold rant looks quite rude to me. (And btw. I do see why this question may collect close votes as e.g. too broad/unanswerable)